# Does 'npm instal'l <package_name> install the latest version of a package or the latest compatible with the version of node installed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

Does **npm install <package_name>** install the latest version of a package or the latest compatible with the version of node installed?

What will happen in these 2 cases?

**Case 1:**
Node version in the directory is 10.16.0.
Will 'npm install xyz' install the latest xyz or the latest compatible version with 10.16.0?

**Case 2:**
Node version in the directory is 10.16.0
Will 'npm install -g xyz' install the latest xyz or the latest compatible with the version of node installed globally OR will it consider 10.16.0?

Answer (score 2):

**Answer**
Latest Version
**HOWEVER**

If the package is already installed in a project or contained within the package.json file,  then the version string Is what NPM will try and use, Which may contain a Caret(^) which tells npm Not to update the Major Version.

For more info read below

Npm install will always install the latest Full Release build of the package (Skips `-tag.x` versions) unless manually specified, which can potentially be incompatible with some versions of node.  Not all packages specify the engine it is compatible with so sometimes you have to do some digging or trial and error.

You can Manually select a version by adding `@` to the package.

For instance, `npm install xyz@10.16.0` will install that specific package version. You can also prefix a version number with a caret (^) to install the latest Minor build, or a tilde (~) to specify the latest patch version.
For example
xyz@^1.2.0 could install say 1.8.0, and xyz@~1.2.0 could install 1.2.9, but Never 1.3.0

For more info on versioning strings read up on Semantic Versioning aka SemVer

https://github.com/npm/node-semver#versions